# unable to access json server

Tags: json-server, json-serialization

I created a mock json server and trying to open in browser ,landing in the following error:

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES 127.0.0.1:8000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1378:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1491:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:55:10)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1357:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Please help.

Comment: Probably :8000 is already in use, try to change it to some unused port.